# MySQL : Use JSON_ARRAY content in SELECT IN query

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I got the two following tables

In the 'items' table, desc column is a JSON array

Table **items**

```
+--------+--------+-------+
|item_id | name   | json  |
+--------+--------+-------+
| 1      | Item 1 | [1,2] |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

Table **descriptions**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | description |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | First desc  |
+----+-------------+
| 2  | Second desc |
+----+-------------+
```

I would like to retrieve all the descriptions for a prticular id.

I have tried this, with no luck:

```
SELECT id, description 
FROM descriptions 
WHERE id IN (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$[*]') 
             FROM items 
             WHERE item_id=1)
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JSON function `json_search()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search), which is available from MySQL 5.7 onwards:

```
select i.item_id, i.name, d.id, d.description
from items i
inner join descriptions d on json_search(i.json, 'one', d.id) is not null 
where i.item_id = 1
```